# Connect points of Highcharts x-range series

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to achieve an effect as close to following
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ugfp.png).

I would like to avoid using Highchart's SVGRenderer so I am looking for any other solution to connect bars on my x-range series chart.

Following fiddle is what I've come up with so far: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakub_noga_antsolutions/xsLr1y2w/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 7, 10),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 9, 25),
      y: 0,
      color: '#83d6e7'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 9, 25),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 10, 40),
      y: 1,
      color: '#669aab'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 10, 40),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 11, 41),
      y: 2,
      color: '#3c6677'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 11, 41),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 14, 14),
      y: 2,
      color: '#3c6677'
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 14, 14),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 15, 13),
      y: 1,
      color: '#669aab'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with solution that satifies my requirements. I'll use a `line series` and simply hide it behind `x-range series` using proper `zIndexes`.

jsFiddle from question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: You can also consider a waterfall chart type. Check here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/waterfall, https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dynv7Lxu/